# Printing c++ variables with other variables changes the value

Tags: c++, c++14

why does the value of counter variable become 0 when it is printed the first time and then when it is printed the second time alone it shows the correct value?

```
//global counter variable 
int counter = 0;

int fibo(int n){
    counter++;
    if(n<=1)
        return n;
    else
        return fibo(n-1) + fibo(n-2);
}

int main()
{
    for(int i = 0;i<10;i++){
        counter = 0;
        std::cout << i << " " << fibo(i) << " " << counter << std::endl; 
        std::cout << counter << std::endl;
    }    
}
```

The output is:

0 0 0
1
1 1 0
1
2 1 0
3
3 2 0

Comment: Because the first time the value of `counter` is checked is **before** `fibo` has been called. Don't assume that things on the left hand sideo of `<<` are evaluated before things on the right hand side of `<<`.

Comment: @john But OP has tagged with c++17, and from that standard, `fibo(i)` is guaranteed to be evaluated before `counter`.

Comment: @cigien Well spotted I didn't look at the tags. But obviously the OP cannot be compiling with C++17.

Comment: @john Or it's an msvc bug :)

Comment: Does msvc12 support C++17?

Comment: Can you please update the question with the exact compiler settings, and compilation flags you are using? The code looks correct, and shouldn't print the output you're seeing.

Comment: ***Does msvc12 support C++17?*** No it does not even fully support c++11

Comment: Isn't this UB??

Comment: @cigien sorry for the wrong tag i was using c++14, which is the default version in Visual Studio 2019...I've updated the tag :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confused about the order things happen. Specifically you are making assumptions about the order of things in your `cout <<` statement which are not justified.

Something like the following is happening

```
1) The value of `counter` is checked and saved somewhere (the value is zero)
2) `fibo` is called are the result saved somewhere (now `counter` has been incremented)
3) The saved result from `fibo` is printed
4) The saved value of `counter` is printed
```

This is all perfectly legal until C++17. With C++17 there was a change to the language which says that the left hand side of `<<` must be evaluated before the right hand side. So with your compiler set to C++17 you should get the output you expect.

With my compiler MSVC 2019 and with the language set to C++17 I get the correct output for C++17.

```
0 0 1
1
1 1 1
1
2 1 3
3
3 2 5
5
```